# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i'm trying to use a view controller that is already active in the app, i'm doing something like this:

```
if TabBar == nil {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        TabBar = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBar") as! UITabBarController
        self.presentViewController(TabBar!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        self.presentViewController(TabBar!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

in "TabBar" view controller i have the same method

```
if(Queue == nil)
    {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    Queue = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Queue") as! UITableViewController
    self.presentViewController(Queue, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else
    {
    self.presentViewController(Queue!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

everything good here, but when i go again to "TabBar", i get the error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller
```

i know i can't present modally an active controller, but i don't know how to "make visible" "TabBar" view controller again, any idea ? thanks

Comment: You need to dismiss your viewcontroller instead of presenting in `Queue` class.

Comment: I did it already and it works, thanks bro